# how create and show multiple thumbnail in asp

Tags: asp.net

I want to develop web page in asp(2.0) c#. in this page I want to create and show multiple thumbnail. For example c:/image  and this folder have 5 .jpeg file. When run my web page then show all thumbnail of 5 images without saving thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can help you.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imagebrowser.aspx

and one more
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/ThumbViewerControl.aspx